# Is there any chance to extract specific permissions from few roles and create a new role with them

Tags: azure-rbac, azure-identity

I want to create custom Azure role by extracting few properties from couple of roles like User Administrator and Application Administrator.

I saw few blogs and articles on creating custom RBAC role but my need is for Directory roles.

**Permissions needed**

```
microsoft.directory/users/*
microsoft.directory/groups/*
microsoft.directory/applications/*
microsoft.directory/serviceprincipals/*
```

How to create custom directory role in my case?

Any inputs are needed

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create custom role in Azure AD, you need to have either **Azure AD Premium P1** or **P2 license** along with `Global Admin` or `Privileged Admin` roles.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I have **`Azure AD Premium P2`** license for my Azure AD tenant like below:

[image]

To create **custom role** in Azure AD, you need to follow below steps:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Roles and administrators -> All roles -> New custom role***

[image]

In Basics tab, enter custom role name and select ***Start from scratch option -> Next:***

[image]

In Permissions tab, you can select the ***permissions*** based on your requirement in the list like below:

[image]

After selecting all required permissions, you can click on **Create** in **`Review + Create`** tab like below:

[image]

After that, **custom role** created successfully in Azure AD like below:

[image]

You can assign that **custom role** to Azure AD users like below:

***Go to Azure Active Directory -> Roles and administrators -> All roles -> Click on your custom role -> Add assignments***

[image]

I assigned that **custom role** to one Azure AD user like below:

[image]

You can select the **type** based on your need and assign role accordingly like below:

[image]

After few minutes, it assigned to the **user** successfully like below:

[image]

**Note** that, you cannot find ***New custom role*** option if your tenant doesn't have required license.

I have another tenant with **`Azure AD Free`** license like below:

[image]

When I tried to create custom role, ***New custom role*** option is `greyed out` like below:

[image]

So, make sure to have required **licenses** and **roles** before creating Azure AD custom roles.